# Separating Minecraft mod versions

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-mods

I like playing Minecraft with mods and I have always used version 1.7.10, but lately mods have been updated to version 1.9 or 1.10 and I want to have them in two versions at a time. Example: shaders mod in 1.10, more wolves in 1.7. How do I do that?

I've tried just putting all the mods in the folder 'mods' with different versions, but it didn't work. I had both forge 1.10 and 1.7. If anyone has advice on how can I separate the mods versions, please help me. I still use the old Minecraft launches 'java', not the new one that doesn't include Java.

Answer (score 1):

If i understand you correctly, you want to use your shader mod for minecraft 1.10 and your more wolves mod for minecraft 1.7 in the same version of minecraft (im guessing 1.10). If that is the case, as far as i'm aware, there is no way of getting those two mods to work with each other in the same version of minecraft.

What you can do is download and install the shader mod for minecraft 1.7 and install that in your minecraft 1.7 version, and just wait until the more wolves mod is released for 1.10.

Comment: that was a problem i had before, thank you for taking the time to help me.

Answer (score 1):

I have found that creating version matching sub-folders in the `mods` folder works for me.

[image: folder structure]

This allows me to have my version specific mods without swapping mods (.jar files) in and out every time I change profiles.

**UPDATE**: This method doesn't seem to be working anymore.  However, the goal can be accomplished by setting a different game directory (and mods folder therein) for each profile/version you have.  See the [forum](https://www.minecraftforge.net/forum/topic/36522-structure-change-quotmodsquot-folder-location-or-name-with-configuration/).